# How to add setCenter on Map that is controlled by Radio button inside the List that is populated by .Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem because i have this List that is populated by .each loop, and in every item on the list there is address with Radio Button, Now my question is how can i focus or setCenter when the Radio button is selected because i tried `getElementByID` but it only focuses on the last queried address. . Thanks in advance for the one who will help me :)

This is my set of Codes

```
function initialize() {
  var minZoomLevel = 4;
  var zooms = 7;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  // Used to Set the Center of the Maps on the Logged User
  $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadAddress', function Geocoding(address) {
      $.each(address, function () {

          customerlocationID = this["ID"];
          var currValAddress = this["AddressLine1"];
          var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
          var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
          LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
          var addresse = {
              zoom: 16,
              center: LatLang,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), addresse);

          var link = $('<input type="radio" name="a" id="radio' + customerlocationID + '"/><label>' + currValAddress + '</label>').data('location', LatLang);
          $('#initialPlace').append($('<li id=\'List\' class=\'List\'>').append(link));
          var radio = "radio" + customerlocationID;
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(radio), 'click', function () {


          });
          // Bounds for North America
          var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
            new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90));

          // Listen for the dragend event
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
              if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
              // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

              var c = map.getCenter(),
            x = c.lng(),
            y = c.lat(),
            maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
            maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
            minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
            minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

              if (x < minX) x = minX;
              if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
              if (y < minY) y = minY;
              if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

              map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
          });

          // Limit the zoom level
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
              if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
          });
      });
  });
  if (customerlocationID != 0) {

      codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
  }
}
```

the code where i want to control the setCenter of map is here

```
var link = $('<input type="radio" name="a" id="radio' + customerlocationID + '"/><label>' + currValAddress + '</label>').data('location', LatLang);
$('#initialPlace').append($('<li id=\'List\' class=\'List\'>').append(link));
     var radio = "radio" + customerlocationID;
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(radio), 'click', function () {
        //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); // or whatever
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you should put the event handler on each radio which would call the maps setCenter() method. Something like this:

```
function initialize() {
    ...
    ...
    var map = new google.maps.Map(...);
    ...
    ...

    $('#initialPlace input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        map.setCenter($(this).data('location'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . . stucked in this problem for 2 hours :( 
Savior!